# Is there any interesting application when viewing one-hot vector as unit vector?

Tags: one-hot-encoding, vector-space-models

From [One-hot - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot#Natural_language_processing):

> In natural language processing, a one-hot vector is a 1 × N matrix (vector) used to distinguish each word in a vocabulary from every other word in the vocabulary. The vector consists of 0s in all cells with the exception of a single 1 in a cell used uniquely to identify the word.

How is that different to unit vector? I suppose that when referring to unit vectors you are more about pure mathematics, while when referring to one-hot vectors you are more about, well, natural language processing. However if you view them as unit vectors, then is there any interesting application follows up? For example, what space does it form? I guess it's a Hilbert space on ℝᴺ, with N is the number of unique word. But that's all I know.